# Tracking Maintainability index (MI) in Java

Tags: java, indexing, maintainability

I need a good fast, reliable (open source would be a plus) tool for Java for tracking Maintainability index and simliar code metrics to show the customer the progress of working on refactoring issues.

What would be your suggestion to apply?

Comment: Ah, but how do you index the reliability of your indices?  :P

Comment: purely from coincides of tool's generated results and my subjective feedbacks from working with the code :)

Answer (score 1):

[Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) is a pretty great tool for tracking all sorts of metrics against a number of projects and maintaining a history over time.

> SONAR is an open source quality management platform, dedicated to continuously analyze and measure source code quality, from the portfolio to the method.

- [Installation guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Install+Sonar)
- [See an example of Sonar in action](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/) against a number of open source projects.
- [Sonar in a nutshell](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+in+a+nutshell)

Answer (score -1):

A very interesting and usable tool for this is [Lattix](http://www.lattix.com/). It checks all class references to create a dependency matrix which is quite a good metric for maintainability; if there are a lot of dependencies in your codebase, then a change in one place will more likely cause a cascade of changes in other classes. I'm not saying it is the only way to measure maintainability, but I think it might be one of the best approaches.

Cool extra feature is refactoring support, which allows you to plan refactoring (to reduce unwanted dependencies) and gives you a list of TODO tasks to complete it. And it is visually quite intuitive, so you can easily track the 'health' of your project at a glance.

Comment: hmm... Lattix seems very usable especially with that diagram of dependencies, but I need to show some numerical value of code "before" and "after" and MI fits perfect for my needs, but for some reason besides of JHawk which seems a proprietry project I haven't found any other tools (or IDE plugins) for Java platform so far :(